# ¿Cómo ignorar lo que sigue a una letra concreta?

Tags: php

Estoy creando una sesión para un usuario, y lo que quiero conseguir es que el password me lo acepte con cualquier texto que siga a una S, he probado con lo siguiente pero solo me lo acepta poniendo justo lo que esta entrecomillado.

```
if ($_POST['password'] == 'S%'){ 
    #codigo
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que una cadena es un array de caracteres, otra forma de hacerlo sería comparando el índice `[0]` de la cadena.

Veamos un ejemplo donde además controlaremos si hay datos en el POST. Aquí vamos a usar un ternario para evaluar, guardaremos el valor en `$mPass` y luego tomaremos su primer caracter mediante `$mPass[0]` para hacer la comparación.

```
$_POST=array('password'=>"SAdbQWZvfrDyZwz=3i,EqN8BfK8{FkkA>M+XGsm]y,)EJky%cRnaXg7dHegrDsh9j{");

$mPass= ( !empty($_POST['password']) ) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL;
if ($mPass && $mPass[0]==='S'){
    echo "OK";
    #Code
}else{
    echo "Muy mal";
}
```

Sólo por curiosidad, creo que sería interesante conocer lo más óptimo a nivel de rendimiento, para casos masivos de comparaciones.

Comment: @cooper ahora que comentas puede que tengas razón, fue lo que interpreté al leer esto: *«lo que quiero conseguir es que el password me lo acepte con cualquier texto que siga a una S»* y viendo la forma en que usaba el comodín (`S%`). De todos modos me queda la duda y espero que Cisco confirme si es eso lo que se requiere o no.

Comment: Si, ambas respuestas son adecuadas, he usado la de @cooper ya que me vale y es menos codigo, pero la tuya también es buena para validar mejor el password, muchas gracias a todos por molestaros en ayudarme y explicarlo.

Answer (score 2):

El carácter comodín se utiliza en `MySQL` (u otras bases de datos, imagino). Para `PHP`, ese carácter es exactamente eso, un "tanto por ciento". Es decir, no tiene un significado especial.

Lo que quieres hacer, lo puedes hacer de varias formas. Te propongo una de ellas:

Utiliza la función [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php)

Esta función devuelve la posición del carácter (o caracteres) que buscas. En caso de encontrarlos, devuelve la posición donde comienza(n) ese/esos caracter(es). En caso contrario, devuelve FALSE (ya que la primera posición corresponde al índice 0).

Osea, en tu caso sería algo así:

```
if (strpos($_POST['password'],'S') !== FALSE){
    #codigo
}
```

No obstante, tienes que tener en cuenta, o tienes que tener cuidado con varias cosas:

- No se si aceptas como válida una cadena que acabe en 'S'. Es decir, que no tenga nada detrás. Por ejemplo: 'ARBOLES'. Según el código que querías poner, sí la aceptarías porque el caracter comodin (en `MySQL`) significa algo así como: "sea lo que sea, aunque no haya nada", pero eso depende de ti.
- Ten en cuenta si admitirás también como válido el caso de la "s" minúscula, ya que la función `strpos` es "case-sensitive", es decir, distingue mayúsculas de minúsculas. Si quieres aceptar ambas, [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.stripos.php) te servirá. (La "i" viene de "insensitive").
- Fijate que la condición de igualdad que he puesto es "!==". Esto es importante ya que si tu palabra empieza por "S", el valor de esa función te devolverá 0 (SALUDO, por ejemplo), y para `PHP` 0==FALSE es cierto, pero 0===FALSE no lo es. Si tienes dudas sobre esto, echale un vistazo a la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/types.comparisons.php), que lo aclara bastante bien.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar esta expresión regular, que te acepte que al incio de la cadena sea una 'S', si es así te manda que si coincide, si no, te manda que no coincide.

```
<?php 

    $var = 'Sopa';

    if(preg_match("/^S/", $var)){

        echo "coincide";

    }else{


        echo 'no coincide';
    }

     ?>
```